# In $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, why the point at infinity is a solution to the equation of euclidean lines in $ \mathbb{C} $?

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $ \overline{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$. We know that in $\mathbb{C}$, every euclidean line is of the form

$$ \beta z + \overline{\beta} \overline{z} + \gamma = 0 $$
where $ \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let us $L$ be the set of solutions of the equation above in $ \overline{\mathbb{C}} $. My question is that why $  \infty \in L $?

I know that we can construct a sequence $\{a_n\} \subset L \cap \mathbb{C}$ in the way that $ |a_i| $ s become greater and greater, and therefore become closer to $\infty$, and we can show that $\infty \in \overline{L}$. But from there on, I don't know how to prove $  \infty \in L $. I aimed to prove that $L$ is closed, but I didn't succeed. Also our professor remarked that $ \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is compact. From the compactness of $ \overline{\mathbb{C}} $ I can just conclude that for any open cover $ \{ \mathcal{O}_i\} $ of $ L \cap \mathbb{C} $ there's a finite subcover $ \{ \mathcal{O}_{i_j}\}_{j=1}^n$ such that $ \infty \in \{ \mathcal{O}_{i_j}\}_{j=1}^n$. Also it was noted that $ L \cap \mathbb{C} $ is continuous, but I couldn't see how that might be helpful (also I wasn't sure what he meant by continuous, because I'd just seen continuity as an attribute of functions, and had not seen it for sets).

Comment: This is just a matter of definition.  How do you define "the set of solutions of the equation above in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$", given that the equation does not make sense when $z=\infty$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not sure if I understood what you meant. But can we be sure that the equation does not make sense for $z = \infty$? Maybe it makes sense, in some sense; and we just have to prove that $ \infty \in L$ in a way other than substituting $\infty$ for $z$.

Comment: But you have simply not defined what $\infty\in L$ means.  Without defining what you mean you cannot possibly prove anything.

Comment: If $+$ and multiplication by a constant are still continuous on $\overline{\Bbb C}$ as well, which I believe is the case, we can see $L$ as the set $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ where $f$ is continuous and so $L$ is closed (hence compact) in $\overline{ \mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see. So could you guess why our professor said such thing? Maybe I'm missing a point which could be fixed? 
Maybe this was also related that the open discs around $\infty$ are defined in this way
$$ U_{\varepsilon}(\infty) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > \varepsilon\} \cup \{\infty\}$$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't realize how you've defined your $f$?

Comment: @Kooranifar $f(z)=\beta z + \bar{\beta}\bar z + \gamma$ as in your description.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh I see, that seems to me right. So now I wonder what you think about Eric Wofsey's point. How does your argument relate to his?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I would appreciate an answer to my question in the previous comment.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why should $f(\infty) = 0$?

Comment: Continuity of $f$ at infinity.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If we take $\beta = 1$ and $\gamma = 0$, why should $\infty + \overline\infty = 0$? Whatever $\overline\infty$ is (I think it should be $\infty$), it does not work.